# Construct a date from parts in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, datepart

I am using SQL Server 2008 and trying to form a query that will use a `CASE`statement with a date calculation to return one of two dates depending on what day of the month the calculation results in.

The goal is if the calculation (in query below) CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + LEAD_TIME results in a day between the 1st and 15th, then assign the 15th of that month. Otherwise, return the last day of that month.

For example, `if CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + LEAD_TIME = 07/12/19, return 07/15/19`.  `If that calculation = 07/16/19, return 07/31/19`.

This seems like it would be possible using `DATEFROMPARTS` but I believe since I am using SQL Server 2008 that function is not defined (that is the error I am returning). Any ideas on a work around?

SQL:

```
 SELECT I.po_number, 
       I.po_item_number AS 'po_item',
       S.orderentry_date, 
       I.po_req_ship_date, 
       I.ex_factory_date, 
       I.del_indicator,
       H.po_type,
       H.vendor_no,
       CASE WHEN DATEPART(dd,(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + MM.IAM_MAN_LEAD_TIME)) BETWEEN 1 AND 15 
            THEN DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(yyyy,(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + MM.IAM_MAN_LEAD_TIME),mm,(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + MM.IAM_MAN_LEAD_TIME),15)
            ELSE DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(yyyy,(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + MM.IAM_MAN_LEAD_TIME),mm,(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + MM.IAM_MAN_LEAD_TIME)+1,0))
            END  AS 'LT_CALC',
       H.po_created_by,
       I.comment


FROM   rbk_sap_user..vw_po_header H 
JOIN   rbk_sap_user..vw_po_item I ON H.po_number = I.po_number
JOIN   rbk_sap_user..vw_mm_material MM ON I.material = MM.material
JOIN   (SELECT order_no,
               orderentry_date 
        FROM   asagdwpdx_prod..SimoxOrder1 

        UNION ALL

        SELECT order_no,
               orderentry_date 
        FROM   asagdwpdx_prod..SimoxOrder2 

        UNION ALL 

        SELECT order_no,
               orderentry_date 
        FROM   asagdwpdx_prod..SimoxOrder3
         ) S ON S.order_no = H.ahag_number

WHERE   S.orderentry_date BETWEEN '01/31/2019' AND '02/13/2019'
AND     I.del_indicator <> 'L'
AND     H.po_type NOT IN ('02','06','10','UB')
AND     MM.business_segment_code NOT IN ('420','421','422','424')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert all the parts of the date to `VARCHAR` and string them together to `yyyy-mm-dd` format, and then `CONVERT` to`DATETIME`.

```
 SELECT 
 ...
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(dd,(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + MM.IAM_MAN_LEAD_TIME)) BETWEEN 1 AND 15 
            THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(yyyy,(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + MM.IAM_MAN_LEAD_TIME)))+ '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART (mm,(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + MM.IAM_MAN_LEAD_TIME)))  + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, 15))
            ELSE DATEADD(DAY, -1, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(yyyy,(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + MM.IAM_MAN_LEAD_TIME)))+ '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(mm,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + MM.IAM_MAN_LEAD_TIME)+ 1)  + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, 1)))
            END  AS 'LT_CALC'
...
```

Note that in the `ELSE` statement, the logic to get the last day of the month is to go the first day of the following month, and then use the `DATEADD` function to subtract one day. [The SQL Server function `EOMONTH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) , introduced in SQL Server 2012, eliminates the need for that logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT CAST(LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + LEAD_TIME, 103 ),2) as int)
```

then

```
CASE WHEN CAST(LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + LEAD_TIME, 103 ),2) as int) < 15 THEN 
  ....
ELSE
  ....
END
```